# How to monitor which request on which URL creates high load on database(mysql) and php?

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I'm interesting in how i can monitor which request on which URL creates high load on database(mysql) and php scripts. Now i use zabbix(2.4), but i cannot find something what can me help with this. Maybe anybody can advise me some tools, ideas for scripts or maybe another monitoring system for this goal? I've seen that NewRelic have such this functionality, but it's too expensive for me.

P.S. [It's](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/web_monitoring) not enough for me

Comment: You need PHP profiling.

Comment: profiling is interesting, but does not cover the entire range of tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pinba](http://pinba.org/) fully meets my objective. The reports take away by the bash script, and then will draw graphs in zabbix.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following things:

1. Logging for mysql slow queries http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html. It is rather intensive, so only enable it brieflly-watch out for performance issues.
2. If you use memcache look into that, if you don't then you probably should be using it anyway for performance reasons.
3. Enable mysql query log http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html.
4. Get logs from the webserver and tie them with the query log to get a sense of what is happening on the server
5. Php profilling

Comment: slow log is enabled. I can add query log, but how i can compare mysql with http?

Comment: You have time stamps on both of them, depending on the query the mysql-slow querry will start 1-2-3 minutes afterwards when it decides that it has found a slow query.